# Can't perform a post request using Angular 4 to Laravel action

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, angular, http

My post request just doesn't work when submitting data to a Laravel action. I am brand new to Angular. By doesn't work I mean the request is made but I get 500 error and the row isn't inserted in the database.

In angular I have a form component that defines this method. The method is executed then the submit button is pressed.

```
 send(form: any): void
 {


  this.http.post('http://www.example.com.br/services/sendMessage', { "subject": "static subject" }).subscribe((res: Response) => {  });

 }
```

My Laravel action is this

```
  public function sendMessage(Request $request)
{

   $subject= $request->input("subject");

   //code omitted  for brevity
 }
```

I performed a test with Fiddler and it worked after I added "Content-Type: application/json" (I get 500 error but the row is inserted). so I tried to add a content type to my post request in Angular but it didn't work. I looked at the request header provided by developer window of Firefox but it seems that it didn't set the content type.

```
 send(form: any): void
 {

  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  this.http.post('http://www.example.com.br/services/sendMessage', { "subject": "static subject" }, options).subscribe((res: Response) => {  });

 }
```

Could the issue be CORS?

### Updated

when the button of my form component is clicked I get this in the browser console

```
ERROR Object { _body: error, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Object, type: 3, url: null }
```

Comment: Do you see anything in the browser console?

Comment: what exactly is the error you receive in the console when you make a request?

Comment: please check the network tap in your dev tools and see what exactly the error is

Comment: It is a CORS issue. I switched to Chrome, I was using Mozilla, and it showed right in the console window. For development one should always use Chrome specially when it comes to Angular development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what you can do there is a helpful package called [laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) which allows you to send Cross-Origin Resource Sharing headers with Laravel middleware configuration. cross-origin issue basiclly occurs when you make http requests from a different domain.

the installation process:

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors
```

then Add the Cors\ServiceProvider to your config/app.php providers array:

```
Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider::class,
```

in your pp/Http/Kernel.php add this to your $middleware array

```
protected $middleware = [
    // ...
    \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class, // add this
];
```

You can publish the config using this command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider"
```

Comment: Please let me know if you have any problem or if my answer is not working for you

Comment: Yes, anyone handling CORS should use the laravels-cors package. But in my case it is not a good idea to use it as a global middleware so I added it as a route middleware.  protected $routeMiddleware = [
         'cors' => \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class] and use in a route Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function(){
Route::post('services/sendMessage', 'ServicosController@sendMessage');

});